# Calculating a container width is incorrect when based on REM as apossed to PX

Tags: css, sass

I have the following card:

```
.card {
    margin: $v/2 $h/2;
    width: $card-width;
}
```

and I want fit 3 card in a container so I calculate the container width:

```
$container-max-width: ($card-width + $font-size-base) * 3;
```

When $v and $h are defined using PX this is working fine:

```
$card-width: 340px;
$font-size-base: 15px;

// This is working
$v: $font-size-base;
$h: $font-size-base;
```

But when they are defined using REM it's not working

```
// This is not working
$v: 1rem;
$h: 1rem;

$container-max-width: ($card-width + $font-size-base) * 3;
```

An [example pen can be found here](https://codepen.io/haki/pen/qXvwNB).

I thought that rem = font-size so the two calculations should be identical, so **why the calculation using REM is not working?**

Comment: rem = relative font size to the root element, or html element. For most browsers that is defined as 16px. You would need to inspect the root element to verify its effective font size.

Comment: I set the font size on the body tag instead of on the HTML. post an answer and i'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: You can also try calculating the width of the container using: `width: calc(340px * 3 + 1rem * 3)`. This way there is no difference between SCSS and real `rem`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEXoQq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rem = relative font size to the root element, or html element. For most browsers that is defined as 16px. You would need to inspect the root element to verify its effective font size.